# Eclipse wizard plugin receives empty selection the first time

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm developing an Eclipse SWT wizard, which is working very well, except for one problem. When I run my eclipse plugin application (from Eclipse, using "run as" -> "Eclipse application"), when I open the wizard for the first time (by right-clicking on a Java class in the Project explorer and selecting New and choosing my wizard), the *IStructuredSelection* object passed into my *INewWizard* implementation's *init()* method is empty (in the debugger I see "<empty selection>"), so the plugin recovers no information about the selection.

After the first time, if I do exactly the same thing again (or if I do it selecting a different Java class), the selection object is not empty and the plugin successfully recovers all the info about the current selection.  It's always only the first selection after start-up which is empty.

Any idea why this happens and if there's a fix or a workaround?

Comment: Note this is Eclipse plugin code not plain SWT. I take it this is actually `INewWizard` you are implementing since `IWizard` doesn't have an `init` method. Does selecting the class and then right clicking after doing the selection work?

Comment: I corrected the interface name in my question (it's INewWizard - thanks for catching that).  And no, the first time after start-up, even if I left-click and then right-click I get the same behavior.

Comment: It's only in the development run/debug environment that I encounter this issue.  I tried exporting the plugin and installing it in another eclipse, and for that installation I do not encounter the issue.